# Title for PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, legending

Is it possible to put a title to `PlotLegends`? Say you have chosen `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"`. Now it would be neat to add a title like `f(x)` to it.

Comment: You find an example in the documentation of `PlotLegend\LegendContent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've missed an example as [Ulrich Neumann](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53677/ulrich-neumann) pointed out. The solution is e.g.

```
PlotLegends -> 
 SwatchLegend[{0, 3.3, 6.7, 10, 13, 17, 20}, 
  LegendLabel -> "mu"]
```