# How to put a title to PlotLegends?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, visualization, plot-themes

I want to put a title to the plotlegends I am using. I get a solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201353/title-for-plotlegends) which says to use `PlotLegends ->  SwatchLegend[{0, 3.3, 6.7, 10, 13, 17, 20},  LegendLabel -> "mu"]`.  But I also want to place the legends where I want like using `PlotLegends -> Placed[Range[1, 6, 1], {0.2, 0.3}]`.

How can I do both?

Edit:
As the answer was given, the wrapping works, but there is still a problem, i.e my plot looks like this: [image]

Where I want to name the legends as "H".
But when I do that Swatchlegend thing it becomes like this :
[image]

I want to keep the markers and colors same.
What should I do?

Comment: `parametricData = Table[100 - t*x^2, {t, .1, .6, 0.1}, {x, 0, 8}];
ListLinePlot[parametricData, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[Automatic, Range[1, 6, 1], 
    LegendLabel -> "H"], {.2, .4}]]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`PointLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PointLegend.html), but you should provide more details so others can reproduce your results.

```
mu = {0, 3.3, 6.7, 10, 13, 17, 20};
pl = PointLegend[mu, LegendLabel -> "mu", LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
   LegendLayout -> "Row", LegendMarkers -> Automatic];
fns = Table[n^(1/p), {p, 7}, {n, 10}];
ListLinePlot[fns, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[pl, Top]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap Placed around the legend. Here's an example modified from the SwatchLegend documentation:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[SwatchLegend[{"first", "second"}, 
LegendLabel -> "legend title"], {0.2, 0.3}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, it gives what I wanted. But there is a problem. I have markers in my plot like triangle, circles tc which came from the 'PlotMarkers-> Automatic' comment. But here all the legend markers are squares. I know there is a option called 'LegendMarkers->' but it doesn't give what I want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `PlotLegends - > Placed[labels, Top, Labeled[#, legendlabel, Top] &]` .

Using the example input from Tim Laska's answer:

```
mu = {0, 3.3, 6.7, 10, 13, 17, 20};
fns = Table[n^(1/p), {p, 7}, {n, 10}];

ListLinePlot[fns, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[mu, Top, Labeled[#, Style["mu", 16], Top] &]]
```

[image]

You can further embellish the appearance using the third argument of `Placed`:

```
ListLinePlot[fns, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[mu, Top, Panel @ Labeled[#, Style["mu", 16], Top] &]]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[fns, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends ->  Placed[mu, Top, 
   Framed[#, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray], 
       RoundingRadius -> 5, ImageMargins -> 5] & @
     Labeled[#, Style[Row[{Spacer[5], "mu"}], 24, "Section"], {{Top, Left}}] &]]
```

[image]